# How check check-box dynamically in click event using Angular.js/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to check check-box when user will click on a button the check box will selected using Angular.js. My code is below:

```
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="answer_{{$index}}_check" 
   ng-model="answer.check" 
   ng-checked="answerIsSelected($parent.$index, $index)" 
   ng-click="toggleAnswerSelected($parent.$index, $index)" 
   ng-disabled="isDisabled($parent.$index, $index)" 
   ng-true-value="true" 
   ng-false-value="false" 
   style="margin-left:10px;"
 /> 
 </td>
<input type="button" value="Edit" ng-click="getValue()">
```

When user will click on `edit` button the check-box should be selected. I am providing my code in [this Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/14TWUgs7DpwdmmPz7cIv?p=preview). You can find there is store button and edit button. When user will select some value and check-box click on store button, I need to store all value. When user will click on edit button, the stored value will set on required row check-box.

Comment: How do 'user select some value'? By checking the checkbox?

Comment: Please go to plunkr code.There are some more drop down.You can select there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it is simply:

```
$scope.getValue = function(){
      $scope.days.forEach(function (day) {
        day.answers.forEach(function (answer) {
          answer.check = true;
        });
      });
  }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/LXl01lnROyjLZXUtRllx?p=preview

Comment: @satya Just paste it to your controller where you have getValue function. Here you go: https://plnkr.co/edit/LXl01lnROyjLZXUtRllx?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You need to Add getValue function in your controller.

```
 var self = this;
 self.getValue = function(){
    $scope.isDisabled = function(dayIdx, answerIdx) {
       console.log('isDisabled', $scope.selectedAnswers[dayIdx].chkbox);
       return (!$scope.answerIsSelected(dayIdx, answerIdx) 
                  &&  $scope.selectedAnswers[dayIdx].chkbox.length === 2);
    };
 };
```